# Change Number format of column to currency in R

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I have imported a dataset which contains a currency but R has converted it to a numeric. The columns is display below:

```
Tariff
2.9
2.9
1
1.6
```

It should look like

```
Price
2.90
2.90
1.00
1.60
```

If possible if the € symbol was displayed before it, it would be even better. I think **digits=2, nsmall=2** would be somewhere near correct.

Comment: See `format()`, `formatC()`.

Comment: R isn't Excel. It doesn't have column level formatting support. If formatting is important to you, you need to format it at the time of presentation. R wants to keep it as numeric for calculations as long as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You should most probably continue to store the values as numeric, so you can easily perform operations on them.

When you want to display the numbers formatted as currency you can use `format`:

```
> paste(format(tariff, nsmall=2), "€")
[1] "2.90 €" "2.90 €" "1.00 €" "1.60 €"
```